# Select tag on top of image

Tags: html, css

So, I have an image
`<img src="images/head-outline-th.png" alt="HeadOutline">`

And I want there to be a select tag on top of this image

```
<select>
<option value="Helmet1">Helmet1</option>
</select>
```

I want the end goal to be like this

[image: FinishedProduct]

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can set a background-image for the select, there is no way to make it applicable to the select's options.  You can set a background-color but thats it. And there's also no way to make the background-color of an option be transparent  Sorry thats not what you want to hear, but there it is.